# My RGB variables are not working on SCSS/SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, codepen

When trying to apply the following to my SCSS:

```
$main__blue: 130, 207, 236;

:root {
    --main__blue: #{$main__blue};
}

h1{
  color: rgb(var(--main__blue));
}
```

I get the following error from compiler:

> Compilation Error Error: Function rgb is missing argument $green.
> on line 44 of sass/c:{...}\assets\css\style.scss
> color: rgb(var(--main__blue));

I don't want to declare the variable as RGB (in which would solve my problem), because I want later on to reuse it as an RGBA.

The strange part is that when applying the same code to [my CodePen](https://codepen.io/brendonmedeiros/pen/PoQOJBv), it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong and how can it be solved?

VSCode with Live Sass Compiler extension.

Comment: Your code is working as it is also when compiling with Webpack using `"sass": "^1.37.5"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be related to the VSC Live Sass Compiler.

**Don't use this extension: Live Sass Compiler by Ritwick Dey**

You are probably using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) extension: Live Sass Compiler by Ritwick Dey. It's widely used, but is no longer supported by the author. Consequently, the SASS version isn't updated. This extension might produce the error you are describing.

**Use this extension: Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks**

You should use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass) extension: Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks. As the author states: *A big thank you to @ritwickdey for all his work. However, as they are no longer maintaining the original work, I have released my own which has been built upon it.*

Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: The problem was the extension, as you said. After installing the new compiler you mentioned, my problem was solved.
The "old" Live Sass Compiler (by Ritwick Dey) seems to not function very well.
I recommend downloading the "new" Live Sass Compiler (by Glenn Marks).

Oh, only if I had asked before, you'd have saved me a few hours of google searching for a problem that didn't even exist hahaha.

Comment: You're welcome. :) I wasn't completely sure if that's the solution, but then you said: *The strange part is that when applying the same code to my CodePen, it works perfectly.* Anyway, have a nice day!